# "The professor does the attendance in his room" is grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

I know that attendance for students means "being present in the class".

How can I say that the professor answers the <s>doubts</s> **questions** in his room, for example Mondays between 4 and 5 pm?

Could it be like this?

> The student attendance is Mondays between 4 and 5 pm in my room.

Comment: Are you trying to say, “The professor holds a review session Mondays between 4:00 and 5:00 pm.”?

Comment: hmmmm! Maybe! if it is the special day that students one by one go to professor's office each Monday and ask their ambiguities, yes!

Comment: Questions that do not use inversion are grammatically correct?? :) One does not **do(* attendance; one **takes** attendance. Also, professors never answer doubts in English. Doubts are answered by snake-oil salesman and spiritual counsellors and religious mystics and young mothers and motivational speakers. Professors answer questions only, never doubts. :) For these many reasons I'm going to reassign your un-inverted question to our site for English Language Learners.

Comment: Although it makes no difference to the question itself, why was *doubts* crossed out and replaced with *questions*? There's nothing wrong with doubts. (Although they are normally addressed rather than answered.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentence "The professor does attendance in his room," the word "attendance" means "roll call," a process undertaken by a person to ensure whether persons on a list are present or absent.

In the sentence "The student attendance is Mondays between 4-5 pm in my room," by "attendance," you seem to be suggesting that the time the professor has set aside to tend to his students questions or concerns is Mondays between four and five in the afternoon.  That's not a proper use of the word attendance, not to mention you stating the time incorrectly (i.e., the dash in "4-5" is already conveyed by the word "between").

To convey what you're trying to convey in that sentence in the manner it is normally conveyed in an academic setting, write:

> I hold office hours Mondays between 4 and 5 pm.

If by "in my room," you mean the professor's classroom, not his actual office, then you would add "in my classroom" to the end of the sentence.  Even if those hours do not actually transpire in his office, the term for what you are describing in academia is nonetheless referred to as "office hours."